# multiplicacion de matrices en java error en el resultado

Tags: java, poo, matrices

Tengo que multiplicar dos matrices y generar una tercera con el resultado..No encuentro el fallo en el codigo pero tengo fallas en el resultado si me podrian ayudar se los agradezco.

Mis matrices y la funcion que la llama

```
int matriz[][] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int matriz2[][]= {{9,7,8},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matriz1.multiplicar(matriz2)));
```

y mi clase con el metodo:

```
package matriz;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Matriz {
    private int matrizA [][];
    
    
    public Matriz (int m [][]){
        matrizA = new int [m.length][m.length];
        matrizA = m;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Matriz [matrizA=" + Arrays.deepToString(matrizA) + "]";
    }

    
    public int [][] multiplicar(int matrizB[][]){
        int resultado [][] = new int[matrizA.length][matrizB[0].length];


        if(matrizA[0].length == matrizA.length){
            for(int i =0;i<resultado.length;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<resultado[0].length;j++){
                    for(int k = 0;k< matrizB.length;k++){
                        resultado[i][j]+=matrizA[i][k]*matrizB[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return resultado;
        }
//RETORNA MATRIZ VACIA SI FALLA EL IF
        return resultado;
    }

    
} fin de la clase
```

El resultado es este

```
30,23,19 
84,65,58 
138,107,97
```

La primer columna esta bien, pero dsp le agrega o le quita el valor del primer indice de la primer matriz.
En 23 me deberia dar 24, en 65 me deberia dar 69, en 107 me deberia dar 114,
Y en la otra fila donde esta el 19 deberia ser 18, dsp 58 deberia dar 54, y 97 deberia dar 90!

Comment: No entiendo tu código o falta algo. ¿Esto de dónde sale?: `matriz1.multiplicar(matriz2)`. ¿De dónde sale `matrizA`? ¿Podrías aclarar esas dudas?

Comment: Es una clase! no subi todo el codigo pero si confunde lo agrego!

Comment: Claro que ayuda, puedes leer [mcve]. Es importante dar la mayor cantidad de detalles para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: ahi agregue lo que faltaba!

Answer (score 1):

si lo que buscas es únicamente multiplicar ambas matrices, revisando tu Matriz de resultados veo que esta misma es correcta. Por ende tu código también lo esta.

*Si lo que buscas es un resultado distinto a la multiplicación de ambas matrices, ¿nos podrías compartir más información?, o compartirnos en el por qué crees que tus resultados son incorrectos.*

Las multiplicaciones que se hacen para terminar de calcular tu primer iteración del arreglo de salida es:

1. (1 * 7) + (2 * 5) + (3* 2) = 23
2. (1 * 8) + (2 * 4) + (3* 1) = 19

La forma en la que se esta calculando cada indice lo podemos ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: La forma en la que se esta calculando cada indice lo podemos ver en el siguiente ejemplo:]

De igual manera de dejo la siguiente liga donde explican mas a detalle :

- [Enlace](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-multiply-two-matrices)

Espero esta información te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: @BetaM Si lo que se busca es solamente multiplicar dos matrices, entonces su código es **Correcto**. Si lo que se busca es que el resultado sea distinto a la multiplicación de ambas matrices entonces la pregunta esta mal formulada.

Comment: Busco la multiplicacion!! pero no me da correctamente el resultado. El codigo aparentemente esta bien aplicado, pero los resultados estan incorrectos. Fijate en una calculadora de matrices y te daras cuenta lo que digo. Lo que quiero es multiplicar, como decis vos, el problema es que la multiplicacion como tal no me da bien los resultados

Comment: El resultado es correcto, los resultados que tu estas esperando es basandote si tu matriz fuera distinta, veo que en tu matriz2 inicial tienes int matriz2[][]= {{9,7,8},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}}; y estas esperando los resultados de como si tuvieras int matriz2[][]= {{9,8, 7},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}};

Comment: si uso una calculadora de matrices el resultado da lo siguiente 
 30  24 18 
 84  69 54 
138 114 90

Y este me arroja el codigo.. entonces creo que hay algo mal en lo que busco hacer
30 23 19 
84 65 58 
138 107 97

Comment: Creo que el error se encuentra en tu segunda matriz, ya revise con una calculadora online y el resultado es correcto, veo que en tu segunda matriz pones los números en una mala secuencia, pones {9, 7, 8} en vez de {9, 8, 7}

Comment: nooooooooooo jajajajaj, muchas gracias. Odio estos errores.